# Metadata navigation and Search reads from different sources, inside my parent site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, navigation

I have an enterprise Wiki site collection, and it have 5 sub sites under it.
Currently I found these two points:-

1. When I am at the Site collection parent site, and I search for certain word, then SharePoint 2013 will search all the pages within the parent site and the 5 subsides to find the word. And will return the related pages (wiki pages).
2. I have enabled Meta data navigation, which allows users to filter the wiki pages based on the wiki column. So I thought that by default I will get the same behaviour, that if I’m at the parent site and I click on a wiki category , then SharePoint will search all the pages within the parent site and within its sub sites, and return the pages that are linked with the wiki category. But what happened is that SharePoint have filtered only the parent pages, and it exclude the subsites.

So my question is whether I can force the metadata navigation to search both the parent site + sub sites pages , when the user click on a wiki category from the parent site? Instead of just searching inside the parent site pages ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Comment: The metadata navigation control you are using is only able to filter a single list or library, hence the behaviour you see above..

Comment: so what other approaches i can follow to have a general metadata navigation that search all the sub sites ,, same as the search functionality..

Comment: There is no OOTB way of searching in a metadata hierarchy (the part you are using is not searching really, it does a filtering with SPQuery). You can add metadata managed properties as refiners for search, but they will not show hierarchically. I guess you would have to write a custom control that renders the metadata tree and performs a search